# Can we use a header in paragraph in a html document?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the Html.I was trying to change some properties of a header inside a paragraph with the help of classes and id.

```
          <div class="article">
            <h1> I am here </h1>
              <p> 
                 where are u? 
                 <h1>   I am looking for u. </h1>
              </p>
         </div>
```

If I am using `.article > h1` selector it is selecting both of the `<h1>` . I came to know that we cannot select single h1 . Plz help me.

Comment: No, you should not be using heading tags in paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first-child` to match the first sub element :

```
div h1:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedp3/)

CSS selectors are powerful. If you want to learn them, I recommand you to try this game-like tuto : [CSS Diner](http://flukeout.github.io/).

Comment: That code would **still** select the `h1` **inside** the p tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D did you just open the demo ?

Comment: That does work but only because the browser is moving `h1` outside of the `p`. It doesn't fix the syntax issue

Comment: @3rror404 you are right. I answered about the selector he should use if he wants to select the first child of a tag. I didn't talk about the syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see what I wated to do.

Comment: My point was that in browsers that don't auto-correct the syntax, this will still select both `h1`'s so you can't rely on this working

Answer (score 4):

You can't nest block level (`h1`) elements in `p` tags.

Your selector `.article > h1` will select both `h1` tags because your browser is moving the nested `h1` outside of the `p` tag to make your code syntactically correct

Your code is probably being changed to something like the following by your browser:

```
    <div class="article">
        <h1> I am here </h1>
        <p>where are u?</p>
        <h1>   I am looking for u. </h1>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i want to select by article class as I edited.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question correctly until you fix the invalid syntax. The other answers using `first-child` or `first-of-type` are relying on the browser correcting the syntax for you which might not be the case for all browsers.

Comment: You have `h1` within `p` which is invalid

Comment: Yeah that I wanted to know whether it is valid or not. I did not have any issue with my browser as far as syntax is concern but when i wanted to select both h1 i got an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the first h1 use `.article > h1:first-of-type`, if you want to select the second use `.article > h1:last-of-type`.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible but problem is that if you make header in paragraph then it will start to the new line.
if you make cascading style sheet  then it is possible

```
<div class="article">
  <h1> I am here </h1>
  <p>where are u?
  <h1>   I am looking for u. </h1>
  </p>
</div>

.article p h1
{
  margin:(set required margin) ;
}
```

Comment: This would not work. `.article p h1` match a `<h1>` into `<p>` into a `<div class="article">`. So second one and not the first. btw, you still have the syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the child pseudo-selectors (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YU79W/

```
.article h1:nth-of-type(2) {
    color:red;
}
.article h1:nth-child(1)
{
background:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

There are any number of other methods you could use to select just one of an element contained by another. Study: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and practice, practice, practice :D

Answer (score -1):

Why not give the h1 an ID?

```
<div class="article">
        <h1 id="main">I am here </h1>
          <p> 
             where are u? 
             <h1>   I am looking for u. </h1>
          </p>
</div>
```

Then select it with #main{}.

Or you could use ".article h1:first-child" in this instance since it is the first child.

Comment: Id is not a good solution here. Too powerful for this case. I would recommand it only if OP wants an anchor to this title. If you want more info about the problem : [Don t use ID selectors in CSS](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/).

Comment: I disagree.  Many articles have tailored intro H1 tags that are very modular when used across a span of several articles.  I can only assume (not defined) that since the class is "article", this  may be the case.  Your article proves no wrongdoing in web standards, and I do not appreciate the downvote.

Comment: @aloisdg Not to mention, your code answer would assume that he wants EVERY first h1 tag inside a div to be styled that way, therefore, your answer is far more incorrect.

Comment: `wrongdoing in web standards` not at all. I use id a lot. This comment got an id. I just think, this is a case where he belongs. By the way, if OP need an id, he should use an id. :)

Comment: @aloisdg Just know, that If I could return the favor on the down vote for your answer, i certainly would as it is a less practical approach than my own.